# Pythonic way to import and use data as object attributes

Tags: python, class, import, attributes

I am working with data that is used as variables after they are imported. I would like to then use the variables in an object as attributes.

So far I have accomplished this by writing an ImportData class and then it is composed into another class, Obj, that uses it for other calculations. Another solution i have used, is to inherit from the ImportData class. I have an example below:

## defining data class

```
class ImportData:
    def __init__(self, path):
        # open file and assign to some variables
        # such as:
        self.slope = 1
        self.intercept = -1
```

## solution 1: use composition

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, data_object):
        self.data = data_object

    def func(self, x):
        return self.data.slope*x + self.data.intercept


data_object = ImportData('<path>')
obj = Obj(data_object)

# get the slope and intercept
print('slope =', obj.data.slope, '  intercept =', obj.data.intercept)

# use the function
print('f(2) =', obj.func(2))
```

## solution 2: use inheritance

```
class Obj(ImportData):
    def __init__(self,path):
        super().__init__(path)

    def func(self, x):
        return self.slope*x + self.intercept

obj = Object('<path>')
# get the slope and intercept
print('slope =', obj.slope, '  intercept =', obj.intercept)

# use the function
print('f(2) =', obj.func(2))
```

I don't like the composition solution because I have to type an extra "data" every time I need to access an attribute but I'm not sure inheritance is the right way to go either.

Am I out in left field and there is better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sense that the chained attribute access in the composed solution is a code smell is correct: `data` is an implementation detail of `Obj` and should be hidden from `Obj`'s clients, so if the implementation of the `ImportData` class change, you only have to change `Obj` and not every class that calls `obj.data`.

We can hide `Obj.data` by giving `Obj` a `__getattr__` method to control how its attributes are accessed.

```
>>> class ImportData:
...     def __init__(self, path):
...         self.slope = 1
...         self.intercept = -1
... 
>>> data = ImportData()


>>> class Obj:
...     def __init__(self, data_object):
...         self.data = data_object

...     def func(self, x):
...         return self.slope*x + self.intercept

...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         try:
...             return getattr(self.data, name)
...         except AttributeError:
...             raise AttributeError('{} object has no attribute {}.'.format(self.__class__.__name__, name))

>>> o = Obj(data)
>>> o.func(2)
1
>>> o.slope
1
>>> o.intercept
-1
>>>
```

Normally, if python fails to find an attribute of an object - for example `obj.slope` - it will raise an `AttributeError`.  However if the object has a `__getattr__` method python will call `__getattr__` instead of raising an exception.

In the above code, `Obj.__getattr__` looks for the attribute on `data` if it doesn't exist on `Obj`, so `Obj`'s clients can call `obj.slope` instead of `obj.data.slope`.  The re-raising of `AttributeError` is done so that the error message refers to `Obj` rather than `ImportData`

Comment: This is cool, except when someone types "o." the IDE will list data as an option. The other interesting thing is that assignment to o.slope go into o and but does not break the method. Is composition still better than inheritance in this case?

Comment: In this particular case of code completion in IDE's, perhaps not.  If it's a problem you could prefix `data` with an underscore (so `_data`) to signify to readers of the code that you consider it an implementation detail of Obj that should not be directly accessed.  But this doesn't mean inheritance is _better_ than composition, or vice-versa; both have their pros and cons, depending on the problems that you are trying to solve.